# If statement flex slider if mobile

Tags: jquery, html, apache-flex

I was trying to make an if else statement for my flex slider settings. But now the will both play autoplay on screen smaller then and bigger then 768.  // Setup for slider single page
    var winIsMobile;

```
function WinSize(){
    winIsMobile = $(window).width() < 768; // Boolean
} 

$(window).on("load resize", WinSize);

$.fn.flexMobile = function(){
    if (WinSize){
        $(this).flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            slideshow: true
        });
    } else { 
        $(this).flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            slideshow: false
        });
    }

}

$('#portfolio-single .flexslider, #cmyk .flexslider').flexMobile();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do two things in order for this to work. Firstly in your WinSize function instead of assigning your boolean value to a variable you need to actually return it:

```
function WinSize(){
    return $(window).width() < 768; // Boolean
}
```

Secondly in your if statement you need to properly call this function (don't forget the brackets):

```
if (WinSize()){...
```

Try this and if the rest of code is configured correctly it should work.